# Double Hashing with python

Tags: python, data-structures, hash, double-hashing

I'm currently doing hashing in my class.
I need to create a double hashing function which takes a list and uses double hashing and returns a new list.

I understand how a list uses double hashing but I have trouble writing down the code for it.

```
hashkey = key % len(list)
steps = q - (key % q)
new_hashkey = steps + hashkey
#q = double_hash_value
```

This is the double hashing function that I have learned in class. I just have trouble implementing it in the code.

This is my attempt so far:

```
def double_hashing(keys, hashtable_size, double_hash_value):
    hashtable_list = [None] * hashtable_size
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        hashkey = keys[i] % hashtable_size
        if hashtable_list[hashkey] is None:
            hashtable_list[hashkey] = keys[i]
        else:
            new_hashkey = hashkey
            while hashtable_list[new_hashkey] is not None:
                steps = double_hash_value - (keys[i] % double_hash_value)
                new_hashkey = hashkey + steps
            hashtable_list[new_hashkey] = keys[i]
            return hashtable_list

values = [26, 54, 94, 17, 31, 77, 44, 51]
double = double_hashing(values, 13, 5)
print('Double =', double)
```

I'm fairly sure this is close to being right but I'm just making a stupid mistake or something. I understand how double hashing works but this code above does not work.

The output for this should be:

```
[26, None, 54, 94, 17, 31, 44, 51, None, None, None, None, 77]
```

but my output is:

```
[26, None, 54, 94, 17, 31, 44, None, None, None, None, None, 77]
```

The value 51 in index position is not being added.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has two problems as far as I can tell:

Problem 1 is that in your `while` loop, you were using `hashkey` to update the value of `new_hashkey` which meant that if your function failed to find an appropriate index for a given value in the first iteration of the while loop, it would never find it since the value of `new_hashkey` would never change.  Also by simply adding the `steps` to `new_hashkey` you run the risk of having a `new_hashkey` that is greater than your `hashtable_size` which will eventually throw an `IndexError`.  You can fix that by taking that value modulo the `hashtable_size`.
Secondly, your function was returning too early. In your example, it was returning after it encountered `44` (i.e. the first time it entered the `else` block), which was why you weren't adding `51` to your output list. Your return statement should really be after the for loop is finished so that you are sure to add all the values in the `keys` list to your output list.

See the updated code below (changed lines are commented):

```
def double_hashing(keys, hashtable_size, double_hash_value):
    hashtable_list = [None] * hashtable_size
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        hashkey = keys[i] % hashtable_size
        if hashtable_list[hashkey] is None:
            hashtable_list[hashkey] = keys[i]
        else:
            new_hashkey = hashkey
            while hashtable_list[new_hashkey] is not None:
                steps = double_hash_value - (keys[i] % double_hash_value)
                new_hashkey = (new_hashkey + steps) % hashtable_size  ## problem 1 is here
            hashtable_list[new_hashkey] = keys[i]
    return hashtable_list  ## problem 2 is here


values = [26, 54, 94, 17, 31, 77, 44, 51]
print( double_hashing(values, 13, 5) )

[26, None, 54, 94, 17, 31, 44, 51, None, None, None, None, 77]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out man. Thanks also for pointing out my mistakes. I knew I was doing something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

In general, here is how we resolve collision with double-hashing: use the second hash function if there is a collision as follows, to find the next location in hash table T, as shown below:

[image]

Now, let's implement double hashing with the following code:

```
def h1(k, m):
    return (2*k+3)%m

def h2(k, m):
    return (3*k+1)%m

def resolve_collision_with_double_hashing(hastable, keys, m, h1, h2):
    for k in keys:
        index = h1(k, m)
        if not hastable[index]: # no collision
            hastable[index] = k
        else:         # use double-hashing
            v = h2(k, m)
            inserted = False
            i = 1 # no need to check for i = 0, since collision already occurred
            while i < m: 
                index1 =  (index +  v * i) % m
                i += 1
                print('inserting {}, number of probings: {}'.format(k, i))
                if not hastable[index1]:
                    hastable[index1], inserted = k, True
                    break
            if not inserted:
                print('could not insert {}'.format(k))

print('hash table: ' + ' '.join(map(lambda x: str(x) if x else '', hastable)))

m = 11
hashtable = [None]*m
keys = [3,2,9,6,11,13,7,1,12,22]
resolve_collision_with_double_hashing(hashtable, keys, m, h1, h2)

# trying to insert 13, number of probings: 2
# trying to insert 13, number of probings: 3
# trying to insert 13, number of probings: 4
# inserted 13
# trying to insert 7, number of probings: 2
# trying to insert 7, number of probings: 3
# trying to insert 7, number of probings: 4
# trying to insert 7, number of probings: 5
# trying to insert 7, number of probings: 6
# trying to insert 7, number of probings: 7
# trying to insert 7, number of probings: 8
# trying to insert 7, number of probings: 9
# trying to insert 7, number of probings: 10
# trying to insert 7, number of probings: 11
# could not insert 7
# trying to insert 12, number of probings: 2
# trying to insert 12, number of probings: 3
# inserted 12
# trying to insert 22, number of probings: 2
# trying to insert 22, number of probings: 3
# trying to insert 22, number of probings: 4
# trying to insert 22, number of probings: 5
# trying to insert 22, number of probings: 6
# inserted 22
# hash table: _ _ 12 11 6 1 13 2 22 3 9
```